# Why does the /events service sometimes pause for a couple of minutes?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, rate-limit, events, caching

In developing the [firehose service](https://stackapps.com/questions/3324/firehose-json-streaming-event-service), I found that the /events API often "pauses" for a couple of minutes before resuming. Is this a known issue?

Specifically, I am polling /events every 10 seconds using a custom filter with all fields turned on. I'm using the `since` parameter to ask for only events that are newer than the most recent one received so far. I'll always get at least one previously seen event back (and ignore it because I've already seen it). The numbers I'm getting every 10 seconds look something like (count of *new* events):

..., 8, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 4, 1, 3, ...
..., 2, 5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 4, 4, 2, ...

It appears that the events that were not sent during the quiet period are all sent after the flow resumes.

I do recognise the `backoff` element but I'm not receiving any of those.

Comment: i just read this in the docs "the Stack Exchange employs heavy caching and as such no application should make semantically identical requests more than once a minute. This is generally a waste of bandwidth, as more often than not the exact same result will be returned."  the `since` filter is being applied to the cache contents and you are 'overtaking' the cache?

Comment: @russau: That's a good point. If the caching is done at a layer above the API request handler, and during some 10-second period there is no new activity, then subsequent requests will use the same `since` field. That would explain why I never see single 10-second periods with 0 new events.

Comment: @russau: I think you're on to something. I tried adding a random `nonce=` parameter to the query, but that didn't seem to help. Then I tried decreasing the `since=` parameter by 1 every time I got no results, and that does seem to avoid this problem (and I now get individual periods with no new events).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments are more or  less correct; caching applies to the `/events` endpoint just like every other method.

This is by design for now.  We have looked at differing caching policies for `/events` and `/inbox/*` routes, as the minute lag on those methods is a bit heavy handed; though we still need to protect ourselves from abusive requests.