# StackHose: live real-time event stream in your browser

Tags: app, events, streaming, realtime

### About

StackHose is a continuously updated stream of new content from Stack Overflow. It uses the [Firehose JSON streaming event service](https://stackapps.com/questions/3324/firehose-json-streaming-event-service) to get a "push" stream of new event notifications. The newest notifications are added to the top of the list.

#### License

StackHose itself is licensed under the [WTFPL](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/).

#### Link

[**StackHose**](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stackhose.html)

#### Platform

This currently works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. It does not appear to work in Internet Explorer.

### Contact

[Greg Hewgill](http://hewgill.com)

### Code

It's just HTML with a bit of jQuery. Right-click, view source.