# Is there a way (or app) to get realtime updates of new questions with a given tag?

Tags: feature-request, api-v2

According to [Stack Exchange API not realtime?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3543/stackexchange-api-not-realtime), the API does not return results in realtime, but has 1 minute delay for the same query.

Is there a system or an app that delivers new questions in realtime for a given tag? Perhaps by email?

Answer (score 4):

There is an [`/events`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/events) route that:

> "Returns a stream of events that have occurred on the site."

[Greg Hewgill](https://stackapps.com/users/79/greg-hewgill) has created a [firehose JSON streaming event service](https://stackapps.com/questions/3324/firehose-json-streaming-event-service) which closely mimics the Twitter Streaming API.

He has also created a page to demo the service here: [StackHose: live real-time event stream in your browser](https://stackapps.com/questions/3381/stackhose-live-real-time-event-stream-in-your-browser?lq=1)

Comment: That's helpful, but `/events` delays the info by 15 minutes. firehose and StackHose are built are `/events`. Are there any realtime solutions?

Comment: @BSeven: It delays the info by 15 minutes? Where are you reading that?

Comment: It doesn't delay the info. I misread it. "Events are only accessible for 15 minutes after they occurred".