# What about actually identical requests?

Tags: support, discussion, api, rate-limit

Now, it says [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) that I should not make lots of `semantically` equivalent requests. It also says that there is a lot of caching. So I was wondering, what about `exactly` identical requests. Should I wait about a minute in between for them too? Or can I just spam them out as fast as my program can send them, as, like you said, you cache it anyway. Or is it somewhere in between?

Answer (score 1):

> Or can I just spam them out as fast as my program can send them, as, like you said, you cache it anyway.

No.  [The throttle discussion page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) specifically says:

> ... we consider > 30 request/sec per IP to be very abusive and thus cut the requests off very harshly.

And even though the underlying *data* is cached for 60 seconds, the HTML *requests* are not. You'll still burn one quota slot with each call, cached or not, and risk the wrath of a `backoff` flag, or worse.

See also: ["Is it possible to access data in real-time using the Stack Exchange API?"](https://stackapps.com/a/4665/7653).
Once per minute is a pretty reasonable rate to repeat the same request. Multiple times per minute also risks running out of quota -- especially if you make several calls per batch/poll.